# "Sequence contains more than one matching element" onload of any Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, kendo-ui-mvc

I know this issue has arisen many times on Stack Overflow.  I've looked at them, but believe this to be unique:

- I'm not using `.Single()` or `.SingleOrDefault()` in any LINQ expressions
- I checked my models for duplicates, like "Id" and "ID", there are none
- This happens onload of any Kendo UI MVC grids, on any table, on any page in my website that has such a grid, and we have several different pages, each with their own grids

Just some history, we just changed some foreign keys to Guids from IDs (ints) in order to point them at different tables in the database than they are currently in the code.  Models were updated, accordingly. We also added a view for the Kendo grid to be pointed at, and this was changed in the view.  But even grids that have nothing to do with the original or new SQL view/C# models seem to have been affected.  Now, during this phase:

```
public OurDatabase(bool enableLazyLoading=true)
    : base("name=OurDBContext")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<OurDatabase>(null);
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = enableLazyLoading;
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = enableLazyLoading;
}
```

It keeps giving the error "Sequence contains more than one matching element".  It will highlight on that middle line with that error.

Can something changing in the database cause this?  Code that once worked, and hasn't been changed since that time, now does not, and this is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answers to my problem.  Yes, plural.

First, if I commented out the `public virtual DbSet<blah> blah { get; set; }` in the database entity, and everything that had anything to do with its model, the old code would work again.  So that told me the issues were in the model.  I also thought I could name "blah" whatever I wanted.  I found it should be named after the DB or view name, instead, so I updated that, accordingly.

Second, I found out I had some major issues with my models, which I had used some decorations on with little knowledge behind them.  Ex.

```
[Key]
[Column(name:"GUID", order:2)]
public Guid Guid
```

It was #2 because ID was #1, and if I put ID in just like above, I got a green squiggly under ID saying `'MyProject.Entities' hides inherited member 'MyProject.Entities.PersistedEntity<int>.Id'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword.  Otherwise add the new keyword.`
That was because of the `PersistedEntity<int>` inherited class that had Id and Name in it, already, that a team member had added.  I commented that out and declared the ID and Name columns (which also had the green squiggly until commenting out that class) the normal way.

Then I got an error on the composite keys, saying it could not order them (*gee, I wonder why*).  So these are how they look, now:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ID { get; set;}

[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
public Guid GUID { get; set;}

[Key]
[Column(Order = 2)]
[StringLength(60)]
public string Name { get; set;}
```

Which set the ordering and composite key correctly, starting at 0 instead of 1 that I had previously.  I had other columns, too, so I continued with setting the `[Key]` and `[Column(Order = x)]` attributes on those, too.

Third, I also added a decoration above the class, calling it a table, even though this was for a view (weird):

```
[Table("My.View")]
```

Keeping things commented out that relates to adding new models in the controllers seems to be the way to go to troubleshoot this lousy, non-descript error that for me said nothing about the real, underlying issues - at least in this instance.  I also didn't think ALL of my grids would stop working just because I added a model - even ones that were not pointed at the new model or the one it was replacing.

After I got the models with the right annotations, I was able to uncomment out the DbSets in my main database model, and because my team member used "Id", when I re-generated the model, I needed to update the ID the grid was using in the Kendo view:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model
    {
        .model.Id(p => p.ID)
    })
```

Also, note, I was only able to get it fully working after upgrading to Entity Framework 6.1.  Before then, I was getting "Invalid object name 'dbo.My.View'".  Apparently in previous versions of EF, you can't just add a model for a table/view and expect it to find it.